# Question regarding cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose A and B are finite sets and $f:A \to B$ . Prove that if |A| < |B| then f is not onto.

My attempt: Supposedly f is onto, then every element of B is an image of some element of A. But since cardinality of B is bigger than A, then some of the element in B will be the image of different elements of A at the same time, which contradicts the hypothesis that f is a function from A to B.

Is my reasoning correct? And how to put them into the right words. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your reasoning sounds good.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to express it formally.

Comment: Use the pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly does it mean for $|A|<|B|?$ It means that there is an injection $g:A\to B$ with no injection $h:B\to A.$ Now, if we assume $f:A\to B$ is onto, we can pick an element $a \in A$ from each preimage $f^{-1}(b)$, i.e. pick some $a\in f^{-1}(b)$ for each $b\in B.$ Now define $\tilde{f}:B\to A$ given by $b\mapsto a$ where $b$ and $a$ were as above. This map is an injection since $f$ is a function: if $a=\tilde{f}(b_1)=\tilde{f}(b_2)$ then $a$ must have been an element of $f^{-1}(b_1)$ and an element of $f^{-1}(b_2).$ This can only happen if $b_1=b_2$ since $f$ is a function. Contradiction to $|A|<|B|$ since we found an injection $\tilde{f}$ from $B$ to $A$.

Comment: Do you mean that, on other word, we show that if f:A→B is onto, then |A|greater than or equal to|B|, which contradicts the hypothesis?

Comment: Yes, for finite sets this can be done easily with the method above.